# Difference between rows.add and importRow

Tags: vb.net, datatable

When adding a row to a datatable in vb.net, what is the difference between rows.add and importRow?

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim dr As DataRow

'Add row this way...
dt.rows.add(dr)

'or this way.
dt.importRow(dr)
```

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx), only difference I can think of is the value of DataRowState of Row in DataTable and dr.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

both do same functionality adding row to datatable but the main difference is

```
    DataTable dt1=new DataTable();
    DataRow dr1=dt1.NewRow();
    DataTable dt2=new DataTable();
    dt2.Rows.Add(dr1); // will give you error already dr1 belongs to another datatable in that                              //case you can do like this
    dt2.ImportRow(dr1); // safe
    dt1.Rows.Add(dr1); // safe as dr1 Row belongs to DataTable1 so no exception raise
```

hope that will give you an idea..

Comment: So why not always use ImportRow? What's the point in rows.add?

Comment: If we want to make a new row in table we can use row.add.but if you want to import row from another table you can use importrow.So import row basically used for to use another row from different table.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested answer is incorrect.  The MSDN article below shows that dt2.ImportRow(dr1) will NOT import dr1.  This is because it is in a detached state.  Also dt2 has not schema.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx