# Difference Between DataTable.Add.Row(array) and DataTable.ImportRow(row)

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to understand the difference between rows created using the following methods:

```
newTable.Rows.Add(array);

newTable.ImportRow(row);
```

I have a WinForms App which uses both these methods to add rows to a DataTable.
Now when I use that DataTable as the DataSource for a DataGridView I can see 'all' of the rows created using both methods.
However, when I use a loop of the type

```
foreach (DataRow row in newTable.Rows)
{
    //...do work
}
```

The loop only 'sees' the rows created using the ImportRow method.  Its as if the rows created using the Rows.Add(array) don't exist, yet clearly they do because I can see them in the DataGridView when I use the DataTable as its DataSource.

EDIT (subsequent to comment by Rahil Jan Muhammad)

Yes - after a lot of playing around I think the Row Adding Methods are nothing to do with it.  The issue is in the following code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataAllocations.Columns)
{
    if (col.Name == "Allocation")
    {
        col.ReadOnly = false;
    }
    else
    {
        col.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}  
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataAllocations.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("DataGrid, " + row.Cells["AllocID"].Value.ToString() +
                                ", " + row.Cells["Active"].Value.ToString());

    if (row.Cells["Active"].Value == null || (bool)row.Cells["Active"].Value == false)
    {                        
         row.ReadOnly = true;
    }
    else
    {
         row.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

The first loop makes all Columns except Column "Allocation" read only.  The second loop is intended to make even Column "Allocation" read only, if the value in Column "Active" is false.  However what is happening is exactly the opposite.  Those rows where Active is true are read only and vice versa.  So yes, there is something wrong with my 'if' statement.  But what?

Comment: please refer to below link for difference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140158/difference-between-rows-add-and-importrow As far as your issue is concerned that you cannot access rows that are added using newTable.Rows.Add(array). please provide your code so that we can have a look.

Comment: I've added more code now - thank you.

Comment: In you messagebox try to add value of Cells["Active"]. i guess there is something wrong with this IF condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem(logig error):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataAllocations.Rows)
{
 MessageBox.Show("DataGrid, " + row.Cells["AllocID"].Value.ToString() +
                            ", " + row.Cells["Active"].Value.ToString());

if (row.Cells["Active"].Value == null || (bool)row.Cells["Active"].Value == false)
{                        
     row.Cells["Allocation"].ReadOnly = true;
}
else
{
     row.Cells["Allocation"].ReadOnly = false;
}
```

}

your code sets the all row's column readonly.you want to set readonly Allocation column(my code).

Answer (score 1):

**datatable.Rows.Add()**
To add new records into a dataset, a new data row must be created and added to the DataRow collection ( Rows) of a DataTable in the dataset

The **ImportRow** method of DataTable copies a row into a DataTable with all of the properties and data of the row. It actually calls NewRow method on destination DataTable with current table schema and sets DataRowState to Added.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Rows.Add and ImportRow is that if you call Rows.Add, the row is marked as added (so if you send your table to a data adapter, and insert will be generated).  If you use Import row, the row comes in, but it is not in the "inserted" state, and will not generate an insert.

However, I cannot reproduce the behavior that you are describing with AddRow - they show  up in my foreach.

Test code below (this is from LINQpad, if you don't have that, you can change the .Dump() call to Console.Write):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = i;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    row.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

to add row to datatable use **newTable.Rows.Add(array);** and to add rows from other tables to another table we use **newTable.ImportRow(row);**

example :

```
        DataTable dt = GetTable(true);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = 101;
        row[1] = "101";
        row[2] = "101";
        row[3] = DateTime.Now;


        dt.ImportRow(row);

        DataTable dt2 = GetTable(false);

        object[] r = { 105, "Habib", "Zare", DateTime.Now };
        dt2.Rows.Add(r);

        dt2.ImportRow(dt.Rows[1]);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
```

the GetTable method :

```
    static DataTable GetTable(bool isAddRows)
    {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));


        if (isAddRows)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        }

        return table;
    }
```