# More Efficient way to Copy DataRows into another DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

This question is about finding a more efficient way for a simple problem. I have two *DataTables* with same structure (i.e. the Columns have same name with same Ordinals). Let them Call *DataTable A* and *DataTable B*. Assume both have 100 rows. Now I want to copy all the rows of *DataTable B* to *DataTable A* without removing rows from *DataTable A*. So in the end *DataTable A* has 200 rows. I did it as shown below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < B.Rows.Count - 1;i++ )
    {
        DataRow dr = B.Rows[i];
        A.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

The issue is I do not want to loop. Is there a direct way to copy it, without looping. The whole 100 rows at once. Is there a function which specifies the set of rows you want to copy.

Comment: In the end it always come down to a loop. You can disguise the for-loop with linq and what not, but you will always iterate

Comment: @Serv So, this is the best way to go?

Comment: also keep in mind `Add` and `ImportRow` differences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140158/difference-between-rows-add-and-importrow

Comment: Why not `dataTableA.Copy();` or `dataTableA.Load(dataTableB.CreateDataReader());`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append one DataTable to another DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858401/how-to-append-one-datatable-to-another-datatable)

Comment: @agent5566 Thanks man/women (I don't know you are a male or a female agent). It's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no other way of copying multiple rows from one Datatable to another than iterating through all the rows. In fact, on MSDN there is an article telling you how to copy rows between Datatables and uses an iteration loop.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/305346

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your simple approach because it doesnt handle primary key violations. Try BeginLoadData, LoadDataRow and EndLoadData. This should be more efficient. BeginLoadData and EndLoadData call only once.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, your suggested answers. Why are we taking about Primary Keys. I am not using database.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are using a database or not. Dataset is an in memory database with tables (Datatable) and rows (DataRow). Best practice is to make one or more columns the primary key, there are Properties for this in DataColumn. Without this you lose the ability to easily locate rows by their keys, you can only traverse. Please read something about DataSets like here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6.aspx

Comment: As for efficiency: This approach is magnitudes faster if the Datatable is bound to an UI Control, because when you copy the table without BeginLoadData every row will update the UI, with BeginLoadData, EndLoadData this occurs only once. Without UI, I guess performance is nearly the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a new independent DataTable instance to work with and do not need to append rows to an existing DataTable, then the DataView.ToTable() method is very convenient.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f(v=vs.110).aspx

It creates a separate copy with the same schema and content.

```
DataTable objTableB = objTableA.DefaultView.ToTable();
```